# io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.<init>(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V

Tags: apache-spark, netty, shuffle

spark 2.1 whenever shuffle operation, titled exception is thrown. checked netty jars in $SPARK_HOME/jars/ subfolder, same to bin.tgz package. Dont' know where this jar conflict comes from. Can anyone help with this?

lt StreamResponse{streamId=/jars/lpark-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, byteCount=11512003, body=FileSegmentManagedBuffer{file=/app/hadoop/SparkTest/./lpark-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, offset=0, length=11512003}} to /10.0.0.149:42834; closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:651)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:240)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.respond(TransportRequestHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processStreamRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:150)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V
    at org.apache.spark.network.buffer.FileSegmentManagedBuffer.convertToNetty(FileSegmentManagedBuffer.java:133)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:33)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)

Comment: BTW, my application is submitted by spark-submit as a scala jar. Both tested by submitting to a spark standalone cluster and in local mode. Same error.

Comment: full logs are here :